# How can I convert this XAML Content Control to Code Behind in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

So I'm having some trouble converting XAML to code behind. I wanted to create a specific animation and after asking for some help on here, a user replied showing me how to create a custom Content Control I was looking for. He gave me two files: Popup.xaml and popup.xaml.cs. Ideally I'd like to have it all in code behind, but I'm fairly new to C# and WPF development and I'm a bit unsure how to do it.

Here is the XAML file content:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl" 
                x:Class="WpfApplication1.PopupBase"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                Template="{DynamicResource ContentControlTemplate}"
                Visibility="Hidden">

    <ContentControl.Resources>

        <Duration x:Key="OpenDuration">00:00:00.4</Duration>

        <Storyboard x:Key="OpenStoryboard" Duration="{StaticResource OpenDuration}">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="{StaticResource OpenDuration}">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Amplitude="0.4"/>
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="{StaticResource OpenDuration}">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" KeyTime="00:00:00" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
```

and as far as the xaml.cs file, all it had was this:

```
var openStoryboard = Resources["OpenStoryboard"] as Storyboard;
openStoryboard.Begin();
```

Here are my attempts so far trying to convert this all to code behind:

```
Duration time = new Duration(new System.TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,400));    

ContentControl cc = new ContentControl
{
    Opacity = 0,
    Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
};

Storyboard openStoryboard = new Storyboard
{
    Name = "openStoryboard",
    Duration = time
};
DoubleAnimation d = new DoubleAnimation(1, time)
{
    EasingFunction = new BackEase()
    {
        Amplitude = 0.4,
        EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut,
    }
};

ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames oaukf = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
{
    Duration = time,
};
DiscreteObjectKeyFrame dis = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame(Visibility.Visible, new KeyTime());

openStoryboard.Children.Add(d);
openStoryboard.Children.Add(oaukf);

cc.Resources.Add(openStoryboard.Name, openStoryboard);

Storyboard.SetTargetName(cc, "ContentControl");
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm kind of lost here. Any tips/advice would be great!

Comment: Any particular reason why?

Comment: I want to add this Content Control to a button and it would be easier to do it if it was all in code behind than to have a XAML file. Also mostly for organizational purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct this line

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(cc, "ContentControl");
```

with

```
//Double animation
Storyboard.SetTarget(d, ContentControl); // <-- change here
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(d, new PropertyPath("Opacity")); // <-- for WPF
```

Correct also TargetName and TargetProperty for other animations

To add discrete animations, you use the KeyFrames property of ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames

```
ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames oaukf = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
{
    Duration = time,
    KeyFrames = 
    {
    new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame(Visibility.Visible, new KeyTime())
    }
};
```

Comment: I am getting an error that says cannot convert string to System.Windows.PropertyPath on the second line for Opacity. Also how do I make DiscreteObjectKeyFrame a child of ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrame like in the XAML?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Use  Storyboard.SetTarget instead

Comment: I've used SetTarget instead of SetTargetName for the first one, but I'm still getting an error on the SetTargetProperty since the second parameter is a string when it's supposed to be a path?

Comment: I've updated. In UWP, you can pass property name as string. In WPF you need to pass a PropertyPath object.

Comment: Great, it works perfectly! Thanks!! Two more things. In new KeyTime(), how do I set KeyTime to "00:00:00" and how do I set the To="1.0" in <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />?

Comment: Nice! For double animation, just access the "To" property and set it. Like this d.To = 1.  For setting the keytime, use new Timespan () instead. PS: don't forget to accept the answer -)

Comment: Thanks again so much!